# Change of variables to evaluate a double integral - limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Suppose I want to compute
$$ I\equiv \int_R (x+y) \exp(x-y) \, dx\, dy$$
where the integration region $R$ is the rectangle delimited by $(a,b),\,(c,b),\,(c,d),\,(a,d)$, so namely
$$ I\equiv \int_a^c dx\, \int_b^d dy\, (x+y) \exp(x-y) .$$

The obvious change of variables is
$$u=x+y, \\
v=x-y,$$
but I'm struggling to see how the new integration limits on $u,v$ have to be determined.

Can you please break down the procedure?

Comment: @Lorago this is clearly wrong. If you draw it, you'll see that the integration region you proposed looks like a new rectangle rotated by 45 degrees. Instead, I think the integration limits on $v$ must necessarily involve $u$ and cannot be written in terms of $a,b,c,d$ only.

Comment: You are right, my bad

Comment: Why do you want to change variables ? This integral can be solved straightforward without changing variable. By changing variable as you want to do, you are making a simple thing complicated.

Comment: @user295357 I chose two sample functions which exhibit this dependence on $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$. Matter of fact, integrals like this (with different integrand functions) pop up all the time in physics, which is why I'm mostly interested in the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be thought of as integrating $f(u,v)$ over a rectangle which is not aligned with the $u, v$ axes. A possible procedure is to split the integral in 3 pieces, $I_1$ for the 1st triangular region one encounters moving along a constant $v$ line that passes through a vertex, $I_2$ for the middle parallelogram and $I_3$ for the last triangle. One then has to find a way to parametrize the boundaries of such regions.
Take a look at the figure below for reference ($I_1$ in green, $I_2$ in blue and $I_3$ in red), but the gist of it is to find the $u$ coordinate of each vertex of the rectangle, and then find the linear relation between $v$ and $u$. In the figure you can see a different $v$ function for each side of the rectangle.
[image]

More concretely, let the $u$ coordinates of the vertices of the rectangle be $$\{u_0=a+b,~u_1=c+b,~u_2=a+d,~u_3=c+d\}$$ (or switching $u_1$ and $u_2$ so as to have them ordered), and let us denote $v_i$ the $v$ coordinate of each point $$\{v_0=a-b,~v_1=c-b,~v_2=a-d,~v_3=c-d\}.$$
Then, after writing everything in a convenient way with the above definitions, the integrals become:
$$ I_1 = \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\mathrm{d}u \int_{v_0+u_0-u}^{v_1-u_1+u} \mathrm{d} v ~f(u,v)/2$$
$$ I_2 = \int_{u_1}^{u_2}\mathrm{d}u\int_{v_2+u_2-u}^{v_1+u_1-u} \mathrm{d} v ~f(u,v)/2$$
$$ I_3 = \int_{u_2}^{u_3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{v_2-u_2+u}^{v_3+u_3-u} \mathrm{d} v ~f(u,v)/2$$
where the factor $1/2$ comes from the determinant of the Jacobian.

There might be sign errors all over the place, but the essence of the method is there.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a lot of work! At this point, could you write down the final result in your answer, so that it remains for future readers? Thanks!

Comment: I checked the result and it is correct. However, there is a misprint in the figure: the bottom-right function in green should read $v=v_1-u_1+u$, as correctly reported in your derivation.

Comment: No, sorry, I also realized that your figure is terribly confusing. The functions you are writing are not correct, in the sense that if you take a single point $(u_i,v_i)$ in the figure, its coordinates do not satisfy the equation of the corresponding straight line. Your final result is correct for some symmetry reason, and your answer shows a valid procedure, but as it stands I cannot mark it as ``accepted'', because there are problems with the derivation and it would confuse future readers.

Comment: I just realized that the $v$ labels in the horizontal axis are wrong. Let me check if there are other typos of this kind and I will edit the answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I believe the figure should be fine now. The labels were wrong there, but the definitions in terms of $a, b, c, d$ where correct in terms of the integration limits functions. I guess that is why the final result was correct.